# Crash Log symbolication IOS 8.1.2 in xcode 6.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios8.1

I tried to rectify the crash using the crash report under "Windows->Devices->View Device Logs", but the crash log is full of numbers. 
 I tried Re-Symbolicate option, but there is no change. "Exceptional Codes" data is also missing in the report.
  I'm using single Mac System to run the project and view the crash reports.So there should not be any problem about symbolification

#### Any other way to symbolicate ?

```
Identifier:          com.company.app
Version:             2.1 (2.1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      debugserver [227]

Date/Time:           2015-02-23 11:37:37.379 +0530
Launch Time:         2015-02-23 11:29:40.850 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_RESOURCE
Exception Subtype: WAKEUPS
Exception Message: (Limit 150/sec) Observed 298/sec over 300 secs
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Attributed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec04f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec02e4 mach_msg + 36
2   IOKit                           0x2cbfcb72 0x2cbbb000 + 269170
3   IOKit                           0x2cbbfe1e 0x2cbbb000 + 19998
4   IOKit                           0x2cbbffc2 0x2cbbb000 + 20418
5   IOAccelerator                   0x33491646 0x33490000 + 5702
6   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x329813b2 0x3297f000 + 9138
7   IMGSGX554GLDriver               0x2a61240e 0x2a60f000 + 13326
8   libglInterpose.dylib            0x007cfdea 0x695000 + 1289706
9   AppName                         0x00195c72 0x98000 + 1039474
10  AppName                         0x00172356 0x98000 + 893782
11  libglInterpose.dylib            0x0085317e 0x695000 + 1827198
12  QuartzCore                      0x2ebcf7fe 0x2eb75000 + 370686
13  QuartzCore                      0x2ebcf666 0x2eb75000 + 370278
14  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x3349b828 0x33496000 + 22568
15  IOKit                           0x2cbbf4de 0x2cbbb000 + 17630
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2bc4f0a2 0x2bb93000 + 770210
17  CoreFoundation                  0x2bc5f570 0x2bb93000 + 836976
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2bc5f50a 0x2bb93000 + 836874
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2bc5db0c 0x2bb93000 + 830220
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2bbab3bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2bbab1ce CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
22  GraphicsServices                0x32f8f0a4 0x32f86000 + 37028
23  UIKit                           0x2f1baf9c 0x2f14d000 + 450460
24  AppName                         0x0015f0c2 0x98000 + 815298
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x39e0daac 0x39e0c000 + 6828

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec02a0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x008ef674 0x8e1000 + 58996
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x008e4496 0x8e1000 + 13462

Thread 2 name:  gputools.smt_poll.0x15588960
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ed419c __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39e33a6c nanosleep + 168
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39e339bc usleep + 48
3   GPUToolsCore                    0x0092cff4 0x924000 + 36852
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e90 _pthread_body + 136
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e02 _pthread_start + 114
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f4eb8c thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  GAIThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec04f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec02e4 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2bc5f316 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2bc5d8bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2bbab3bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2bbab1ce CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2c8e4bf8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 260
7   Foundation                      0x2c9330b8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   AppName                         0x00218354 0x98000 + 1573716
9   Foundation                      0x2c9a9b56 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e90 _pthread_body + 136
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e02 _pthread_start + 114
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f4eb8c thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec04f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec02e4 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2bc5f316 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2bc5d8bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2bbab3bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2bbab1ce CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2a8b53ea GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 130
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2a8a7908 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 192
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e90 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e02 _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f4eb8c thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec0540 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x008edaaa 0x8e1000 + 51882
2   MediaToolbox                    0x2d667ff6 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1962
3   CoreMedia                       0x2c402d10 figThreadMain + 184
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e90 _pthread_body + 136
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e02 _pthread_start + 114
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f4eb8c thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.remote
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec04f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec02e4 mach_msg + 36
2   MediaToolbox                    0x2d66d0dc FigExpressNotificationThread + 84
3   CoreMedia                       0x2c402d10 figThreadMain + 184
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e90 _pthread_body + 136
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e02 _pthread_start + 114
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f4eb8c thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec04f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec02e4 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2bc5f316 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2bc5d8bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2bbab3bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2bbf40e6 CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   CoreMotion                      0x2c4aee9a 0x2c46f000 + 261786
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e90 _pthread_body + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e02 _pthread_start + 114
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f4eb8c thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec04f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ec02e4 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2bc5f316 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2bc5d8bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2bbab3bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2bbab1ce CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   CFNetwork                       0x2b760952 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 482
7   Foundation                      0x2c9a9b56 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e90 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e02 _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f4eb8c thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ed408c __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2bc63ae2 __CFSocketManager + 494
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e90 _pthread_body + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f50e02 _pthread_start + 114
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f4eb8c thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ed49cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f4eea8 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39f4eb80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000003      r2: 0x000000dc      r3: 0x000010bc
    r4: 0x0000cf3b    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x006745f8
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00000003     r11: 0x00000003
    ip: 0xffffffe1    sp: 0x006745bc      lr: 0x39ec02e9      pc: 0x39ec04f0
  cpsr: 0x00080010

Bad magic 0x2BBAB1D3
Microstackshots: 1 (from 2147483647-08-23 07:00:00 +0530 to 2147483647-08-23 07:00:00 +0530)
  1 ??? [0x677868]
    1 CoreFoundation 0x2bb93000 + 829633 [0x2bc5d8c1]
      1 ??? [0x676bd0]
        1 CoreFoundation 0x2bb93000 + 836379 [0x2bc5f31b]
          1 ??? [0x676b90]
            1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x39ebf000 + 4841 [0x39ec02e9]
              1 ??? [0x676b54]
                1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x39ebf000 + 5360 [0x39ec04f0]
                 *1 ??? [0x80012f3d]

Binary Images:
0x98000 - 0x2cffff AppName armv7  <f7d35a1c655d3510b2e82a4f84a1cec1> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0107CC0F-E58F-4410-99CF-342284A7BBC9/AppName.app/AppName
0x678000 - 0x67ffff libBacktraceRecording.dylib armv7s
```

Comment: Xcode can't find the matching dSYM for the app build that caused the crash, without that you will only see memory addresses for your apps calls.

Comment: Yes you are right, i just now found that the crashed build was replaced by the latest. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate some api for crash report. use the fabric.io api.

Thanks